# Exception calling an URL from a servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets

I'm trying to call an URL (URL contains only json code) from a servlet but I keep getting a read time out exceptions on getInputStream().

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse esponse) throws IOException, ServletException  {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder;
        InputStream in=null;
        String json=null;

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SimpleWeb/users");
        try{
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.connect();    

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            json = stringBuilder.toString();
            System.out.println(json);
        }catch(Exception e){        
            System.out.println(e);
        }finally{
            if(reader!=null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works by replacing `http://localhost:8080/SimpleWeb/users` with `http://localhost:8080/SimpleWeb/users.txt`(but only when called from a plain java app, not a servlet)

Can anyone help to see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please paste the exception / error that you are seeing

Comment: Maybe increase the timeout length?

Comment: OP is getting a `read time out exceptions on getInputStream()`.

Comment: may be because of `conn.setReadTimeout(5000);` you have given only 5 seconds timeout

Comment: Everything is done on localhost so I should get a response in miliseconds. The txt file (json formatted) that is located at http://localhost:8080/SimpleWeb/users is very small. I will try to call this same URL form a plain java application, rather than a servlet to see if the problem exists there as well.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using a Tomcat server. The above code does work in a plain java app if I just replace http://localhost:8080/SimpleWeb/users with http://localhost:8080/SimpleWeb/users.txt.